# Infinite loop in a list procedure

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following block of code:

```
ArrayList<ELPERouteStop> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i < metric.length;i++) 
    {

        /*
         * We get a from object for each row (customer) and a to object for the element
         * of the matrix with the highest metric from the ith customer.
         */
        ELPERouteStop from = all_stops.get(i);
        ELPERouteStop to = all_stops.get(getMaxValue(metric[i]));
        if(i==0)
        {   
            candidates.add(from);
            candidates.add(to);
        }
        for (int j=0; j < candidates.size();j++)
        {
            int k=0;
            if (candidates.get(j) == from || candidates.get(j)==to) 
            {
                k++;
            }
            if (k == 0)
            {
                candidates.add(from);
                candidates.add(to);
            }
        }
    }
```

What seems to be the problem is the change of size of the candidates list at each iteration. 
I need to insert the from and to objects to the candidates list, only if they don't exist already. Hence, I do the check in the second for loop.
When I run the code it appears to enter an infinite loop and I cannot find why.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about caching the length of candidates, not calling candidates.size() on every iteration?

Comment: The variable `metric` appears an array. Is that correct? What does the method `getMaxValue()` do?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Why are you using `==` to compare objects? Are you aware of difference between `==` and `equals` method? What is `k` variable supposed to represent, you are using it like integer but based on your code it looks more suitable to be boolean, or even eliminated and replaced with `else{..}` block.

Comment: Or how about not using your loop but use Arraylist.contains(Object o) method?

Comment: Or if you don't think the elements' order important, you may use Set, which does not add element if it already contains that.

Comment: The whole `int k; if (condition) { k++; } if (k == 0)` thing is over-complicated. Just use `if (!condition)` instead.

Comment: I'm really sorry guys for my programming skills, especially in java, but I only use code to implement my engineering ideas. Your comments were really helpful!

Comment: @RobertKock, yes, metric is an array, and contains doubles. The method getMaxValue returns the max value of a vector.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Collection#contains` instead of iterating the collection each time.

```
List<ELPERouteStop> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i < metric.length;i++) {

    ELPERouteStop from = all_stops.get(i);
    ELPERouteStop to = all_stops.get(getMaxValue(metric[i]));

    if (!candidates.contains(from) && !candidates.contains(to)) {
        candidates.add(from);
        candidates.add(to);
    }
}
```

Or, slightly more efficient - depending on how fast `getMaxValue` is:

```
for (int i=0; i < metric.length;i++) {

    ELPERouteStop from = all_stops.get(i);
    if (!candidates.contains(from)) {
        ELPERouteStop to = all_stops.get(getMaxValue(metric[i]));
        if (!candidates.contains(to)) {
            candidates.add(from);
            candidates.add(to);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reason for infinite loop is this conditional statement **if (candidates.get(j) == from || candidates.get(j)==to)** . As you are using == operator to compare the objects it always returns false because == operator always used to compare the reference of the objects not the values. So k value is increasing exponentially on every iteration so that it leads to infinte looping.[for more details about the == and equals() method](http://www.java67.com/2012/11/difference-between-operator-and-equals-method-in.html)

Solution:

To compare the objects in collection you can use **contains()**. But  for comparing objects you need to **override the equals method in ELPERouteStop** class.

For sample refer:

class Test{

```
String a;

Test(String a){
    this.a = a;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this.a.equals( ((Test)obj).a));
}
```

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

```
    ArrayList<Test> arr = new ArrayList<Test>(4); 

    Test a = new Test("abc");

    arr.add(new Test("abc")); 

    boolean test = a == new Test("abc"); // Returns false due to reference checking

    boolean ans = arr.contains(a); // returns true as this checks with the value
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`I need to insert the from and to objects to the candidates list, only if they don't exist already.` This seems like a good candidate for a `Set`. You could try to use a `Set` instead of a `List` and let the data structure itself implement that constraint for you. If you go with that approach, make sure you override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods for your objects.

Comment: A `Set` won't help because he wants to check both `to` and `from` and add either both or none. With a `Set` it would be possible to add one that isn't present, but not the other that is.

Comment: You could define an object containing both `to` and `from` and create a `Set` of those instead.

Answer (score 0):

In case  order matters:

```
ArrayList<ELPERouteStop> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i < metric.length;i++) 
        {

            /*
             * We get a from object for each row (customer) and a to object for the element
             * of the matrix with the highest metric from the ith customer.
             */
            ELPERouteStop from = all_stops.get(i);
            ELPERouteStop to = all_stops.get(getMaxValue(metric[i]));
            if(i==0)
            {   
                candidates.add(from);
                candidates.add(to);
            }
            else if(!candidates.contains(from)&&!candidates.contains(to))
            {
                    candidates.add(from);
                    candidates.add(to);
            }
        }
```

In case order doesn't matter:

```
Set<ELPERouteStop> candidates = new hashset<>();
        for (int i=0; i < metric.length;i++) 
        {

            /*
             * We get a from object for each row (customer) and a to object for the element
             * of the matrix with the highest metric from the ith customer.
             */
            ELPERouteStop from = all_stops.get(i);
            ELPERouteStop to = all_stops.get(getMaxValue(metric[i]));
       //comment out to optimize
            //if(i==0)
            //{   
            //  candidates.add(from);
            //  candidates.add(to);
            //}
              candidates.add(from);
             candidates.add(to);
        }
```

Comment: Order matters. Your answer was really helpful! Thank you

Comment: @DimitrisBoukosis You're welcome. Also how about putting `else`, in case speed matters.

Answer (score 0):

Since both the loops are for-loop, it's impossible that you enter an infinite loop.

are you sure that the program was stopped in this block ?

I guess it is perhaps just because of low performance making it seems like an infinite loop, try to decrease the size of `metric` and run again to see if the program can stop.

Also you can use `Set` to optimize your code like this:

```
// first declare a set:
Set<int> candidatesSet = new HashSet<>();

// and after added each from/to to `candidates`
candidatedSet.add(from.hashCode())

// replace you second loop with
if (!candidatedSet.contains(from.hashCode()) && !candidatedSet.contains(to.hashCode())) {
    candidates.add(from);
    candidates.add(to);
    candidatedSet.add(from.hashCode());
    candidatedSet.add(to.hashCode());
}
```

Of course, you need to make sure that you `hashCode` **returns distinct int for each different candidate**